# How can I use Gson's TypeToken more compactly?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson to serialize and deserialize some JSON. I have a Guava `ImmutableMap<String, String>`, which I would like to deserialize. I managed to find a [serializer in Google Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper/blob/b529de52c22f30b4d9768475b9b04f82404e5ef6/caliper-util/src/main/java/com/google/caliper/json/ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory.java).

Gson requires a `Type` to deserialize to. I can generate one like so:

```
gson.fromJson(
    serialized,
    TypeToken.getParameterized(ImmutableMap.class, String.class, String.class).getType());
```

The `TypeToken.getParameterized(ImmutableMap.class, String.class, String.class).getType()` part feels very manual and error-prone.

Is there a better alternative that looks more like this?

```
// Does not compile
Type.of(ImmutableMap<String, String>)
```

Comment: No way to do it more compactly. You either use `getParameterized` or use `new TypeToken<T>()` where T is your type literal (`ImmutableMap<String, String>` cannot work, of course). It would be nice if Java would support something like `ImmutableMap<String, String>.type` to return a `ParameterizedType` instance though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to create a `TypeToken` for a parameterized type like `ImmutableMap<String, String>` is `new TypeToken<ImmutableMap<String, String>>() {}` (note the `{}`).